# react-native share doesn't work properly for facebook

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-share

I'm trying to upload base64 image and to set message, title and caption, and it seems that it doesn't work, basically what happens is that image has been uploaded, but rest of params are ignored. Any help?

Here is the part of code

```
const shareOptions = {
    title: "React Native",
    message: "Hola mundo",
    url: result,
    subject: "Share Link"
}

....

Share.open(shareOptions)
```

Also I have tried to share to email end message and title are filled.
Is there some limitations for facebook?

Comment: Which library are you using for share?

Comment: react-native-share (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share)
Also Share from react-native

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not working because Facebook does not support pre-filling the message for users as seen in their Policy.
https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#socialplugins

You should also read the comments [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/39) for more detail.